# API blueprint (e.g.: Apiary) - tool to generate json body from blueprint

Tags: api, apiblueprint, apiary.io

Is there a tool to help in making example JSON bodies from the API blueprint syntax?

For example if I have laid out the attributes like this:

```
+ Attributes (object)
    + data (array)
        + (object)
            + id: 100 (number) - The ID for the particular EPG object
            + title: "Vikings" (string) - The title for the program item
            + lang: "English" (string) - The language that the program is in
            + desc: "Lorem ipsum" (string) - The long description
            + start: 1492700179 (number) - The UNIX epoch timestamp for when the program starts
            + duration: 2816 (number) - For how many seconds the program will last
            + links (array)
                + (object)
                    + rel: "self",
                    + uri: "/epg/100"
                + (object)
                    + rel: "image"
                    + uri: "http://cdn.inquisitr.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Vikings-Season-5-1.jpg"
```

Is there a tool that will generate a JSON body or schema for me from this?   I have googled and looked through the tools at [https://apiblueprint.org/tools.html](https://apiblueprint.org/tools.html#) but none of them seem suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API Blueprint parser](https://github.com/apiaryio/drafter) is able to generate a JSON schema for your MSON data structures, it is just matter of extracting them from the parse result.

You can do it [manually](https://runkit.com/zdne/mson-renderer) but there are as well ready to use [tools](https://github.com/madewithlove/mson-to-schemas) to do that.

Hope it clarifies - I'll make sure to update the tools section!